# unable to run ddd on mac

Tags: mac, terminal, xcode, x11

I am trying to install ddd debugger on my MAC. It installed fine, however when I try to run it I get the following error:

```
bash-3.2$ ddd test
Error: No `Ddd' application defaults file
To resolve this problem, you can:

set the XAPPLRESDIR environment variable to the location of the file `Ddd', or
set the DDD_HOME environment variable to the location of `ddd/Ddd', or
install the `Ddd' file in the X application defaults directory, or
recompile DDD with builtin app-defaults file;
see the `--enable-builtin-app-defaults' option for details.
```

I have X11 installed in my utilities folder. It works coz i use xterm on it quite often.

any ideas how to fix this??
anything I need to add to ./configure or make commands while installing ddd ???

Comment: WHat are the values of the variables in the error? and where is Ddd installed?

Comment: Hi mark 

i downloaded ddd in my Downloads folder and ran the
`./configure && make` command there.

as for the variable i am not sure how to find out the values. I am a noob at programming. If you could tell me how to find out i will report back to you

Comment: If new why not use Xcode as much easier to setup and use?

Answer (score 1):

I was able to fix this from some hints from [this site](http://lists.opensuse.org/archive/opensuse-bugs/2011-04/msg04281.html).

After installing, you run the configure command again. This will create the Ddd file in the ddd folder. Now you can follow any of the steps that are printed out, I personally used the DDD_HOME variable with the patch to the sourcecode directory of ddd, since Ddd is now in $DDD_HOME/ddd/Ddd.